# How to check if number in a list is greater than and in continuation to next number in list

Tags: java, list, number-formatting

I have below a sample list of objects containing startRange and endRange as longs. I want to check if my first element endRange is in continuation to startRange in the next element and generate an output where the range can be shortened if numbers are in continuation. See sample output.

- Sample Input -

  startRange : 1005000, endRange : 1005799
  startRange : 1005800, endRange : 1005899
  startRange : 1005900, endRange : 1005999
  startRange : 2096000, endRange : 2096999
  startRange : 2097000, endRange : 2097999
  startRange : 2205010, endRange : 2205019
- Sample Output -

  startRange : 1005000, endRange : 1005999
    startRange : 2096000,    endRange : 2097999
   startRange : 2205010, endRange : 2205019

This is what I have tried -

```java
List<BinRange> finalRange = new ArrayList<>();
for (BinRange bin : list.getBinRanges()) {
    rangeStart  = bin.getRangeStart();
    rangeEnd = bin.getRangeEnd();
    System.out.println("startRange : " + rangeStart + ", endRange : " + rangeEnd);
    long diff = Math.abs(rangeEnd - rangeStart);
    if (diff == 1) {
        continue;
    } else {
        rangeEnd = bin.getRangeEnd();
        BinRange binRange = new BinRange(rangeStart, rangeEnd);
        finalRange.add(binRange);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate them in consecutive pairs as such:

```
static List<BinRange> check(final List<BinRange> ranges)
{
    // trivial
    if (ranges.size() < 2)
    {
        return ranges;
    }
    var resultRanges = new ArrayList<BinRange>();
    Long prevStart = null;
    for (int i = 1, rangesSize = ranges.size(); i < rangesSize; i++)
    {
        final BinRange prevRange = ranges.get(i - 1);
        final BinRange currRange = ranges.get(i);

        if (prevStart == null)
        {
            prevStart = prevRange.getRangeStart();
        }

        if (prevRange.getRangeEnd() != currRange.getRangeStart() - 1)
        {
            resultRanges.add(prevStart == prevRange.getRangeStart()
                    ? prevRange  // recycle instance
                    : new BinRange(prevStart, prevRange.getRangeEnd()));
            prevStart = null;
        }
        if (i == rangesSize - 1)
        {
            resultRanges.add(prevStart == null
                    ? currRange // recycle instance
                    : new BinRange(prevStart, currRange.getRangeEnd()));
        }
    }
    return resultRanges;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Vala. D. Your solution works fine but it will not add last record to the list which does not have any further startRange record incremented for lastRange value. I'll try to fix it and test it. This is better than what I was trying to break the loop and add to list.
For eg, with this input -  
     {"rangeStart":"5000","rangeEnd":"5799"},
      {"rangeStart":"7000","rangeEnd":"7499"},
      {"rangeStart":"7500","rangeEnd":"7999"},
      {"rangeStart":"9000","rangeEnd":"9600"}

OUTPUT is coming -
  {"rangeStart":"5000","rangeEnd":"5799"}
  {"rangeStart":"7000","rangeEnd":"7999"}

Comment: Ah sure. I updated it to consider disjoint ranges at the last position as well.